How can I use LINQ to filter from a list inside of another list?
Alright, so this is quite hard to explain, but I will do my best.
I have a list filled with books.
All of the books have variables such as Title, publishYear, and Author.
But they also have Genres, and that is where it gets a bit confusing for me.
Because every book can have more than one genre, I made genre a list of its own.
So every book would be structured like this.
Title = "Hello World",
publishYear = 2001,
Genres = ["Horror", "Drama"],

Now, I would like to use LINQ to filter after a specific genre, so if the user would for example want to filter after "Horror", then only those would be displayed.
But since they are in a List of their own, I am having slight issues with it.
This is as far as I got.
This is a quick recreation of the involved pieces of my code.
List<Book> allBooks = new List<Book>();

allBooks.Add(new Book("Hello World", "Tom Burt", 2009, ["Horror", "Romance"] ));
allBooks.Add(new Book("Hello World 2", "Robert Burt", 2004, ["Comedy", "Romance"] ));

var genreBooks = allBooks.Where(x => x.Genres.All(y => y == "Horror")).ToList();
genreBooks.ForEach(book => Console.WriteLine(book.Title));

//Expected Outcome
Hello World
//Actual Outcome
EDIT:
It was solved by just changing All to Any!
Thank you for the help :)

Use Any instead of All

@PeterB I feel so stupid, so close yet so far away xD
Thank you :)

Contains would probably have been easier to understand: books.Where(b => b.Genres.Contains("Horror"))

It was solved by just changing All to Any!
Thank you for the help!
var genreBooks = allBooks.Where(x => x.Genres.All(y => y == "Horror")).ToList();

Became
var genreBooks = allBooks.Where(x => x.Genres.Any(y => y == "Horror")).ToList();


You can accept your own answer to close the question.
